# Back-up restoration via iCloud for WhatsApp's stuck

Tags: icloud, whatsapp.app

I have just re-downloaded Whatsapp and wanted to restore the chats that I have backed up. However, this occurs:

[image]

It has been stuck at 99% for the whole evening. I have tried following the guide WhatsApp published online but to no avail.

Is there anything that anyone knows which can help?